# Efficiently computing all pairwise products of a given vector's elements in NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, linear-algebra

I am looking for an "optimal" way to compute all pairwise products of a given vector's elements. If the vector is of size `N`, the output will be a vector of size `N * (N + 1) // 2` and contain `x[i] * x[j]` values for all `(i, j)` pairs with `i <= j`. The naive way to compute this is as follows:

```py
import numpy as np

def get_pairwise_products_naive(vec: np.ndarray):
    k, size = 0, vec.size
    output = np.empty(size * (size + 1) // 2)
    for i in range(size):
        for j in range(i, size):
            output[k] = vec[i] * vec[j]
            k += 1
    return output
```

Desiderata:

- Minimize extra memory allocations/usage: Directly write to the output buffer if possible.
- Use vectorized NumPy routines instead of explicit loops.
- Avoid extra (unnecessary) calculations.

I have been playing with routines such as `outer`, `triu_indices` and `einsum` as well as some indexing/view tricks, but haven't been able to find a solution that fits the above desiderata.

Comment: "Directly write to the output buffer if possible" Do you mean in reality you have an output array already allocated, or it can be reused multiple times? In the Numba version of @orlp allocating the output array is actually the most time consuming part, not the calculation itself. (12.8 ms only calculation, 43.7 ms calculation+allocation) on my system.

Comment: What I meant is that I would like to avoid unnecessary allocations for any temporary arrays. This would imply that the only allocation would be for the output buffer, and it would get filled with calculation results.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see the possibility of parallelization in the first place. There is some potential...I will add a parallel version.

Comment: @iheap Did either of the posted solutions work for you?

Comment: I am currently using the Numba solution. I will keep the question open for a while in case someone comes up with a clever NumPy-only solution. If not, I will accept the Numba solution in a few days.

Comment: What about NumPy-only solutions in https://stackoverflow.com/a/62015703/? Not clever enough? :)  @iheap

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Approach #1**

For a vectorized one with NumPy, you can use a masking one after getting all the pairwise multiplications with outer-multiplication, like so -

```
def pairwise_multiply_masking(a):
    return (a[:,None]*a)[~np.tri(len(a),k=-1,dtype=bool)]
```

**Approach #2**

For really big input 1D arrays, we might want to resort to iterative `slicing` method that uses one-loop -

```
def pairwise_multiply_iterative_slicing(a):
    n = len(a)
    N = (n*(n+1))//2
    out = np.empty(N, dtype=a.dtype)
    c = np.r_[0,np.arange(n,0,-1)].cumsum()
    for ii,(i,j) in enumerate(zip(c[:-1],c[1:])):
        out[i:j] = a[ii:]*a[ii]
    return out
```

**Benchmarking**

We will include [`pairwise_products` and `pairwise_products_numba` from @orlp's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62012545/) in the setup.

Using [`benchit`](https://github.com/droyed/benchit) package (few benchmarking tools packaged together; disclaimer: I am its author) to benchmark proposed solutions.

```
import benchit
funcs = [pairwise_multiply_masking, pairwise_multiply_iterative_slicing, pairwise_products_numba, pairwise_products]
in_ = [np.random.rand(n) for n in [10,50,100,200,500,1000,5000]]
t = benchit.timings(funcs, in_)
t.plot(logx=True, save='timings.png')
t.speedups(-1).plot(logx=True, logy=False, save='speedups.png')
```

Results (timings and speedups over `pairwise_products`) -

[image]

[image]

As can be seen with the plot trends, for really large arrays, the slicing based one will start winning, otherwise vectorized one does a good job.

**Suggestions**

- We can also look into `numexpr` for performing the outer multiplications more efficienctly for large arrays.

Comment: Why didn't you include the numba version in your benchmark? I'd be curious to see the exact numbers.

Comment: @orlp Because it seemed like [`OP is looking for NumPy based solutions`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62012339/efficiently-computing-all-pairwise-products-of-a-given-vectors-elements-in-nump/62015703?noredirect=1#comment109679448_62012545). Added it anyway.

Comment: Nice, upvote from me. I'm surprised to see that `pairwise_multiply_iterative_slicing` starts winning. I have a suspicion it's because of `output[k] = vec[i] * vec[j]`. I wonder if numba would always be the fastest if we took `vec[i]` out of the inner loop and wrote `m = vec[i]` and `output[k] = m * vec[j]`.

Comment: [Seems like it makes no difference.](https://i.imgur.com/Mtc4c1o.png) On my machine numba is always the fastest though.

Comment: @orlp Kool! Guess for your system you can stretch it to 10K or even more given that you have a lot more RAM to see that iterative one cutting off numba one? Good to see benchit being used at other places :) Same for you.

Answer (score 4):

I would probably compute *M = v<sup>T</sup>v* and then flatten the lower or higher triangular portion of this matrix.

```
def pairwise_products(v: np.ndarray):
    assert len(v.shape) == 1
    n = v.shape[0]
    m = v.reshape(n, 1) @ v.reshape(1, n)
    return m[np.tril_indices_from(m)].ravel()
```

I would also like to mention [`numba`](http://numba.pydata.org/), which would make your 'naive' approach most likely faster than this one.

```
import numba

@numba.njit
def pairwise_products_numba(vec: np.ndarray):
    k, size = 0, vec.size
    output = np.empty(size * (size + 1) // 2)
    for i in range(size):
        for j in range(i, size):
            output[k] = vec[i] * vec[j]
            k += 1
    return output
```

Just testing the above `pairwise_products(np.arange(5000))` takes ~0.3 sec whereas the numba version takes ~0.05 sec (ignoring the first run which is used to just-in-time compile the function).

Comment: This approach creates two temporary arrays (`m` and the return value of `tril_indices_from`), right? I am trying to understand whether it is possible to elide copies.

Comment: @iheap Yes. Use `numba` if you really want to squeeze that last bit of performance here - numpy (unless I missed a very nice function) won't help you further here.

Comment: Indeed, `numba` makes a huge difference and *automagically* converts the naive version to an optimal version. I will wait for a little while to see if anyone can come up with something clever that only uses base NumPy functions; and if not, will accept your answer later on.

Comment: @orlp You could probably make the NumPy version a tad faster by using `.ravel()` instead of `.flatten()`

Comment: @orlp You could use `-1` syntax (`arr.reshape(-1, 1)`) to let `numpy` figure out the missing shape `n` by itself.

Answer (score 0):

You could also parallelize this algorithm. If it would be possible to allocate a large enough array (a smaller view on this array almost costs nothing) only once and overwrite it afterwards larger speedups can be can be achieved.

**Example**

```
@numba.njit(parallel=True)
def pairwise_products_numba_2_with_allocation(vec):
    k, size = 0, vec.size
    k_vec=np.empty(vec.size,dtype=np.int64)
    output = np.empty(size * (size + 1) // 2)

    #precalculate the indices
    for i in range(size):
        k_vec[i] = k
        k+=(size-i)

    for i in numba.prange(size):
        k=k_vec[i]
        for j in range(size-i):
            output[k+j] = vec[i] * vec[j+i]

    return output

@numba.njit(parallel=True)
def pairwise_products_numba_2_without_allocation(vec,output):
    k, size = 0, vec.size
    k_vec=np.empty(vec.size,dtype=np.int64)

    #precalculate the indices
    for i in range(size):
        k_vec[i] = k
        k+=(size-i)

    for i in numba.prange(size):
        k=k_vec[i]
        for j in range(size-i):
            output[k+j] = vec[i] * vec[j+i]

    return output
```

**Timings**

```
A=np.arange(5000)
k, size = 0, A.size
output = np.empty(size * (size + 1) // 2)

%timeit res_1=pairwise_products_numba_2_without_allocation(A,output)
#7.84 ms ± 116 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit res_2=pairwise_products_numba_2_with_allocation(A)
#16.9 ms ± 325 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit res_3=pairwise_products_numba(A) #@orlp
#43.3 ms ± 134 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```